# What is the difference between "coming" or "going" and "heading" somewhere?

Tags: word-choice, differences

What does "We could head that way" mean, exactly? Why should I use "head" instead of "come" or "go"?

Comment: It means point your face in one direction and move that way. See [Fillmore](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) on _coming and going_; but first read [_"May We Come In?"_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf) so you can see how deixis works.

Comment: This is a frivolous question. It is like asking - why use the phrase *stop looking over my shoulders* rather than directly saying *stop micro-managing me*.

Comment: It is like asking - why use the phrase *please carry on* rather than saying *please continue what you are doing*. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To head somewhere generally denotes to start moving, as opposed to '***go***'. '***Head***' is generally used with a direction; '***go***' is generally used with a destination. Notice the difference:

> We could *go **to*** the bar.
>
> We could *head **towards*** the bar.

This is not a strict grammatical difference. It's just the way these words are generally used. '***We could head to the bar***' is equally acceptable, but, like I said, the '***to***' there is meant to denote a direction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question is frivolous. "Come" and "go" sound more imperative. "Head" has more of a "mosey at your own pace" connotation.